# How to create a websocket endpoint in an existing spring application

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I'm trying to make available a new websocket endpoint in an existing spring application.

I'm following the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-handler . But based on documentation I should configure the **DispatcherServlet** or use **WebSocketHttpRequestHandler**.

How can I make available the websocket endpoint without any change in the web.xml config file ?

This is what I tried, but not working (Client error 404 not found).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core" xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
  xmlns:websocket="http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
                           http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
                           http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket/spring-websocket.xsd">

    <websocket:handlers  allowed-origins="*">
        <websocket:mapping path="/ws" handler="websocketService"/>
        <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor"/>
        </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
    </websocket:handlers>    

    <bean id="websocketService" class="com.krios.SocketHandler"/>

</beans>
```

Class file:

```
public class SocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        for(WebSocketSession webSocketSession : sessions) {
            Map value = new Gson().fromJson(message.getPayload(), Map.class);
            webSocketSession.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hello " + value.get("name") + " !"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        //the messages will be broadcasted to all users.
        sessions.add(session);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you the java configuration (you can then change it to xml yourself or use it as java class and scan it from xml)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public MessagingWebSocketHandler webSocketHandler() {
        //handler of your websocket. should be a class implementing WebSocketHandler.
        //You could also extend AbstractWebSocketHandler or TextWebSocketHandler and override methods
        return new MessagingWebSocketHandler(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        WebSocketContainerFactoryBean container = new WebSocketContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(StaticConfig.MAXIMUM_WS_TEXT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(StaticConfig.MAXIMUM_WS_BINARY_BUFFER_SIZE);
        container.setMaxSessionIdleTimeout(StaticConfig.MAXIMUM_WS_SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT);
        container.setAsyncSendTimeout(StaticConfig.MAXIMUM_WS_ASYNC_SEND_TIMEOUT);
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
        webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(webSocketHandler(), "/message").setAllowedOrigins("*"); // you could also get handler from context 
    }

}
```

I hope it hepls.

**update**

I myself don't use xml based  configuration. But the simplest way is to add this java code then scan it from xml. For example, by adding this line to your spring servlet configuration xml you can scan your configuration package or whole project package.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.company.config" />
```

Then your WebSocketConfig class must be under `com.my.company.config`

Documentation Of Websocket support and configuration is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html). On section *Create and Configure a WebSocketHandler* you can read about xml configuration. I havent test it myself tho.

Comment: Hi @SepehrGH, I dont have too much experience with Spring. Do you mind to include in your answer the corresponding xml configuration as well ? It would be really very useful.

Comment: I updated my answer. I usually don't use xml configuration so I can't provide you a code that I have tested myself. But I know component scan can help you scan those configuration files. I also added the link to Websocket Support Documentation. There are bunch of valid codes there that you can use.